# Converting JSON objects in Android with gson

Tags: java, android, wcf

I am new to Java and Android so please bear with me. I am trying to create a function which calls a wcf service and converts the returned result from JSON to a Java object (I pass the type as the object `t`), but it's throwing a null pointer exception on `t`, which must be `null` as I just want to pass an object of the correct type so that it becomes filled when converted. Kindly help me with it.

```
    public static String Post(String serviceURL, Map<String, String> entites,
        Class<?> t) {
    String responseString = "";
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            //now we will try to convert the class to the specified type.
            t = (Class<?>) gson.fromJson(responseString, t);



    } catch (Exception e) {

        responseString = e.toString();

    }
    return responseString;
```

Thanks a lot.

After some tries, I ended up with this code but I am still facing a null pointer exception.

```
    MemberInfo mem = new MemberInfo();

    TypeToken<MemberInfo> m = null ;
    ServiceCaller.Post(getString(R.string.LoginService), values , m);


            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            //now we will try to convert the class to the specified type.
            t = (TypeToken<T>) gson.fromJson(responseString, (Type) t);
```

Comment: When you say it's not working fine, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: The written code throws an exception that t is null , and it must be passed as null..I just want to pass the type , this is what I want .

Comment: So you mean it's not a runtime error, it's a syntax error! Well that is nothing to do with GSson or android... By the looks of the code you're missing a close bracket for the Post method.

Comment: I just fixed the question , sorry I copied the wrong code .. its a runtime exception that t is null .

Comment: Well you need to show a stacktrace (output from logcat) to show exactly what you mean.

Comment: As far as I know you need to pass the `class` and not the `instance` to the method. So it would needs to be something like : `gson.fromJson(responseString, ExpectedType.class);` where `ExpectedType` is the name of the class, that you expect the JSON string to contain

Comment: yes GameDroids , but I want it to be generic , I want to pass different type each time .

Comment: have a look at this: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types

Comment: Dear , I am still facing the error , I am really new to android so you can help me with it , I will update the question with the new code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is impossible. In order for one to do this, gson would have to be able to detect the correct class *only from the serialized string*. However, a single string can be interpreted in many valid ways. For instance, take an example on the gson website:

```
class BagOfPrimitives {
  private int value1 = 1;
  private String value2 = "abc";
  BagOfPrimitives() {
    // no-args constructor
  }
}
```

Using `Gson.toJson` on an instance of this class results in the string:

```
{"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}
```

However, if I made another class identical to the first in all respects but name:

```
class SackOfPrimitives {
  private int value1 = 1;
  private String value2 = "abc";
  SackOfPrimitives() {
    // no-args constructor
  }
}
```

Then this would also serialize to the same string:

```
{"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}
```

My point is that given a single string like `{"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}`, there is no way for gson to determine whether it should deserialize it into an object of type `BagOfPrimitives` or type `SackOfPrimitives`. Therefore, you always have to provide gson with the correct type, because it wouldn't be possible for gson to figure it out by itself.